# Sessions don't persist, even to the next line

Tags: php, session

I'm working on a PHP login/register system, and the login sessions are done using... you guessed it... sessions.

However, sessions simply *do not work.* Here's an example:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['hi'] == "hi";
echo $_SESSION['hi'];
```

It outputs nothing.

My Googling has found me nothing except hints about `register_globals`. My host, [000webhost](http://000webhost.com), has it set to `off`, could that have anything to do with it?

Okay, just got an answer and I realized how stupid I am (it was a mistake, I knew that). No need to post any more answers.

Comment: don't try open register_globals(security reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use = instead of ==

== compares, your comparison evaluates to false, and nothing is modified. But with = you set new values.

Also .. turn on errors!!!

Comment: It worked, and I feel very, *very* stupid.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator, `==` is the comparison operator

Change == to = and you will no longer have an issue.
You should only use == to compare two values to see if the statement is true or false.